# How to Access forLoop data outside the scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [day, setDay] = useState()
  const [time, setTime] = useState()
  let result = []


  //Getting data from backend using axios 

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/data")
      .then(function (response) {
        setData(response.data.slice(1))
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }, [])

  function search(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ((time == data[i][1])) {
         result.push(data[i])
      }
    }
  }
  
console.log(result)

  return (
    <div className='layout'>
      <div className='navbar'><a href='#'>Home</a></div>
      <div className="wrap">

        <form onSubmit={search}>        

          <label for="time">Select Time</label>
          <select id="time" name="time" onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}>
            <option>Select Time</option>
            <option value="8am - 6pm">8am - 6pm</option>
            <option value="10am - 9pm">10am - 9pm</option>
            <option value="9am - 10pm">9am - 10pm</option>
          </select>

          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above react app I am getting data from backend using `axios` and saving it into react state called `data` which is in array form and look's like this:

```
0: Array(8) [ "Honey Baked Ham Company LLC, The", "10am - 9pm", "sun,mon", … ]
​​​
1: Array(8) [ "Ranch 616", "9am - 10pm", "sat,sun", … ]
​​​
2: Array(8) [ "Austin Oaks Hospital", "9am - 10pm", "sun,mon", … ]
​​​
3: Array(8) [ "MN - Carnicerias Lafogata", "9am - 10pm", "tue,thu", … ]
​​​
4: Array(8) [ "Whitney's Magical Treats", "9am - 10pm", "tue,thu", … ]
​​​
5: Array(8) [ "Papadom", "10am - 9pm", "tue,thu", … ]
​​​
```

Also inside the `search()` function I am iterating over data and saving the value in array called `result` using push method.

**While doing `console.log(result)` outside `search()` function I am getting output as `empty array`**  probably because `console.log(result)` statement is running before `result.push()` statement inside `search()` function.

So, **What is the right way to access the value of `result` outside of `search()` function ?**

Comment: You are right, ```console.log``` executed before ```search()``` get called. You may return ```result``` in the end of your ```search()``` function and another end will receive the result OR you may set it to a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the  `result` as a state variable

```
const [result, setResult] = useState()
```

Then,

```
search(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    const arr=[]
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ((time == data[i][1])) {
         arr.push(data[i])
      }
    }
   setResult(arr)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that result will not be used before the search method it self executed, you can try making search method return the result array , and don't do any console.log before you execute the function search